# Before I Go to Sleep - plot issue

Tags: plot-explanation, before-i-go-to-sleep

On the last day of the plot of *Before I Go to Sleep*, Ben/Mike is shown in his car as he leaves the house for the day. On the passenger seat is a second phone that is ringing. That phone shows that the call is from Claire.

We know from a prior conversation between Christine and Claire that Christine had never revealed Mike's name to Claire. We also know that after Christine's description of Ben/Mike to Claire, Claire states that she does not know who Christine is living with.

How can Claire be calling Ben/Mike if she knows the real Ben but does not know the fake Ben?

Answer (score 1):

*Claire* doesn't call *Ben* nor *Mike*, she calls *Christine*. You already said that it's a second phone and in fact **it's *Christine*'s cell phone** that *Mike* confiscated exactly to prevent her being called by *Claire* (or anyone else who could have "dangerous" information, I don't remember if he exactly knew about *Claire*). That is the only reasonable explanation as you said correctly, that *Claire* doesn't know *Mike*.

Comment: Oh ok. That makes sense. I had to google it as just watched film and was confused. Got it now. Good Film! 